# Сборка npm-пакета webpack + typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, library

Всем здравия! Столкнулся с проблемой на ровном месте. Есть задача - собрать небольшую либу и положить в npm, чтобы потом пользоваться. Всё собирается, но в итоге не заводится. Сейчас покажу что делаю.

**package.json** Тут всего чуть-чуть. Вебкак и тайпскрипт по сути и всё.

```
{
  "name": "testlib",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "files": [ "lib" ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3",
    "webpack": "^4.42.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
}
```

Далее есть 2 тс-файла с кодом и один index.ts, который всё экспортит.

**digitMask.ts**

```
export function maskString(str: string, mask: string): string | undefined {
    // тут какой-то код
}
```

**scrollLock.ts**

```
export class Scroll {
    constructor() { }

    lock(): void {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    }

    unlock(): void {
        document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
    }
}
```

**index.ts**

```
export { maskString } from './digitMask';
export { Scroll } from './scrollLock';
```

То есть в итоге всё собирается в один index.js c .d.ts файлами. Я устанавливаю эту либу в проект локально `npm i /local/path/to/project`. В проекте IDE находит эту зависимость, в самой IDE я прекрасно вижу методы класса, но когда пытаюсь использовать, то получаю какие-то ошибки, вроде того, что `Scroll` это не конструктор, а функция из первого файлика не функция. Вот такие

```
Uncaught TypeError: testlib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.Scroll is not a constructor
```

а запускать пытаюсь вот таким кодом

```
import { Scroll } from 'testlib';
import { maskString } from 'testlib';

console.log(Scroll, maskString);

console.log(maskString('123456', '###-###'));
let locker = new Scroll();
locker.lock();
```

Я точно ошибаюсь в какой-то мелочи, но уже третий день не могу найти косяк. Кто может подсказать в чём дело, пожалуста дайте ума :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, проблема была в конфиге вебпака. Поле `output` конфига необходимо указать, что мы билдим библиотеку. Я не разобрался ещё как это работает, но всё завелось. Выглядит это примерно так

```
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'lib'),
  library: 'testlib',
  libraryTarget: 'umd',
  filename: 'index.js',
},
```

Comment: Суть в том, что бандл вебпака для использования в проекте как entry и как библиотека - отличается. Чтобы было понятнее чем, можно посмотреть на начало файлов, которые создаются после сборки.